# Unknown command: schedule/run

Tags: yii2, scheduler

#### What steps will reproduce the problem?

cmd run
/app/yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@console/config/schedule.php

Unknown command: schedule/run
Caused by: Exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "schedule/run".'

#### What's expected?

/console/config/schedule.php

`<?php
use omnilight\scheduling\Schedule;

/**

```
@var Schedule $schedule
*/
$commandBathPath = Yii::getAlias('@app') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'yii ';
if(YII_ENV_PROD) {
$schedule->exec($commandBathPath . 'spider/process-email-pic')->everyTenMinutes();
$schedule->exec($commandBathPath . 'email/send-from-queue')->everyNMinutes(2);
}`
```

#### Additional info

| Q | A |
| --- | --- |
| Yii version | yii2-app-advanced |
| PHP version | PHP version: 7.2.34 |
| Operating system | Welcome to Ubuntu 23.04 (GNU/Linux 6.2.0-32-generic x86_64) |

cmd run
/app/yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@console/config/schedule.php